# Slow loading of rasters from PostGIS. Not use overviews PostGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, postgis

Very slow loading of rasters from PostGIS. The analysis showed that there is no coverage in the table, which means that overviews is not used. The raster is loaded into the database by the raster2pgsql utility.

```
raster2pgsql.exe  -d -I -C -Y -N 0 -r -s 4326 -l 16 t1.tif" -M -P -t 128x128 public.tab0 | psql
```

What am I doing wrong?

[image: extent showing as unknown]